# xelatex & newpxtext: Missing small caps ligatures

Tags: fonts, xetex, ligatures

I'm using the **newpxtext** package with **xelatex**, and I find I'm missing small caps ligatures when I pass the `largesc` option:

```
\documentclass[border=0.4in]{standalone}
\usepackage[largesc]{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
Isomorphism of Infinite Groups. \textit{vs.} \textsc{Isomorphism of Infinite Groups.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note *Innite* instead of *Infinite*. Compare this to the result without `largesc`:

```
\documentclass[border=0.4in]{standalone}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
Isomorphism of Infinite Groups. \textit{vs.} \textsc{Isomorphism of Infinite Groups.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am certainly not savvy enough to suss out what might be happening here; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a curious problem, but using `newpxtext` with XeLaTeX doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: In any case, small caps fonts should not have f-ligatures to begin with.

Comment: I don't think it has f-ligatures, which might be why it omits the FI entirely. Why doesn't it make sense to use `newpxtext` with XeLaTeX, if I may ask?

Comment: `newpxtext` uses legacy fonts, so you just get into problems if you use XeLaTeX with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

It may be that you're not using an up-to-date version of the `newpxtext` package. The most recent version, as of early September 2016, is version 1.301, 2016/08/29.

Here's an MWE that shows that the `fi` ligature as well as the other `f-`ligatures are working with the latest version of `newpxtext`. (They are working with and without the option `largesc`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[largesc]{newpxtext}
\begin{document}
off fit fly office baffle infinite

\scshape off fit fly office baffle infinite
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, the f-ligatures provided by the `newpxtext` package aren't nearly as elegant as those of a "real" Palatino font, say, Palatino nova:

[image]

```
%% Compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino nova} 
\begin{document}
off fit fly office baffle infinite
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. I've verified that I have the most recent version of the package. When I try your MWE, all the ligatures are missing. I can only assume there must be something wrong with my TeX installation.

Comment: Ah — it appears that if I compile my MWE with xelatex, the problem occurs. If I use pdflatex, it works correctly.

Comment: @Derek - Do you have access to a Palatino text font on your system? If so, you may be better off loading the `fontspec` package and loading the text font via a `\setmainfont` instruction.

Comment: I'm marking this correct since it pushed me to move off the `newpxtext` package and fully embrace `fontspec`.

Comment: @Derek That code ought not compile at all with `pdflatex`!

Comment: @cfr - I think Derek was referring to the upper MWE, which does compile under pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, *and* XeLaTeX. It's only under XeLaTeX, though, that untoward behavior is encountered. By the way, do note that the posting's title was changed to inform readers that XeLaTeX was in use only *after* I posted my answer. Thus, I wasn't aware that the author was using XeLaTeX, and I was assuming that pdfLaTeX was in use. (I only noticed this change to the posting's title right now...)